# Why is my Webapplication (WAMP) slow if I request it multiple times with one Browser/Session?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, session

first Request: http://url.tld/calc-sth-complicated

second Request: http://url.tld/simple-view

I have a Webapplication - Windows/Apache/PHP/MySQL. If I use one Browser (one Session) with more tabs to request the Webapplication it seems that the second request waits for the first request.

If I use two Browsers (two Sessions) the second Request does not wait for the first. How can I fix this? What ist blocking? How can I see what is blocking? Why is the second request waiting?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP's default session handler locks the session file while any script which uses the session is active. Doing multiple requests from the same browser to the site forces all but the first parallel request to wait for the session file to become unlocked.

Doing it from two completely browsers, which means two different sessions, lets the requests proceed in parallel, since neither session will lock the other.

If your site requires the ability to do multiple same-session requests in parallel, you should `session_write_close()` as soon as possible in each script. If the script doesn't modify the session's contents, you can do it immediately AFTER the initial `session_start()` call. The $_SESSION array will still be present and readable, even though the session's "closed".

Answer (score 0):

The browser. It has nothing to do with your app; browsers have limits on how many requests they will make to one server at one time.

Comment: Is it possible that the limit in the Browser ist set to one?

Comment: Usually it's two -- but that includes any images, stylesheets, or anything else, if they're on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, suddenly each time after `session_start()`, the next request took some *30 sec* to be executed. I found out that the session file in `c:\wamp\tmp` was locked by the first request for some *30 sec*. During  this time the second request was waiting for the file to be unlocked.

I found out it had something to do with `rewrite_mod` and `.htaccess`.

I disabled `rewrite_mod` and commented out every line in `.htaccess` and it works again like a charm.

I don't know why this happened because I don't remember change any settings or conf on *wamp*.